# <p> keeps on falling out of <div>

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my `<p>` in my `<div>` but it keeps on falling out. I want the div to become larger in height whenever the text inside `<p>` becomes more text.

```css
#service-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.service-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.service-wrapper2 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.service-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 4px solid rgb(94, 106, 124);
  margin: 10px 40px;
}

.container-title {
  width: auto;
  height: 30%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background-image: url("images/drawing.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.service-container p {
  color: rgb(247, 250, 255);
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-wrapper2">
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="container-title">service1</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.

    </p>
  </div>
```

I've got multiple service.containers next to each other but I don´t think it matters for this case.

Comment: div.service-wrapper2 needs a closing tag </div> also I'm not sure you need max-height rule in the selector .service-container p

Comment: Rather than resizing your outer container to fit text, try resizing your text to fit the outer container. Dynamically modifying container sizes can really mess with the look of your page.

Comment: It has one, I forgot to paste it because then I´d have to paste the other 5 .service-container. I´ll edit it.

Comment: Also, if service1 is a title, why not use an <hx> tag?

Comment: @emsimpson92 I´m new to all of this so i just do what looks best to me, thanks for the tip ! Any starting points on how to do it ?

Comment: thebrownkid has the answer you are looking for

Comment: To the user who deleted their answer: I saw you asked about your down vote so I tested your code but didn't get a chance to leave a comment. Your code put all of the text into `container-title` which made the body text formatted like the title. I think you got voted down because your code introduced a new problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. I've made small ammends to your css as well to fix the issue (For eg: removed the `height` from `container-title`).

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

> The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

```css
.service-wrapper2 {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.service-container {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(94, 106, 124);
  margin: 10px 40px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.container-title {
  width: auto;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background-image: url("images/drawing.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.service-container p {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-wrapper2">
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="container-title">service1</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd also explicitly point out that you removed the height from `container-title`. That was enough to fix it when I was messing with the code.

Comment: I removed it plus gave it an added touch for the user's need.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. The lines do break already, but they go outside the .service-container and I want the container to become larger as the text grows.

Comment: @Jonas.D - The snippet in this answer does demonstrate the container becoming larger with more text.

Comment: @Jonas.D It will do it now. Try my snippet with more text and you'll understand.